# How to store user input data from a registration form in mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

My server is running using only node.js and not express. I am using JADE as template to show if the user has registered successfully. I am unable to figure how to use save() function in mongodb.

Comment: Please show us your code you already tried.

Comment: I would love to show the code, but I solved it. The problem was, I tried saving the data in database from client using array in an if/else however it was saves data in database as an object not in array.
Thanks.